# What is the difference between functions that start with "allocate", "create", "initialize" and so on

Tags: naming-conventions

When it comes to naming a function, what are the main differences between the following words: 
"allocate", "create", "initialize", "instantiate", "make", "build", "add" and "insert".

When should I use each word?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I associate *allocate*, *create*, *instantiate* and *make* with the creation of a new object whereas *initialize* is more associated with setting initial values. The words *add* and *insert* are used for functions or methods which add new elements to some collection, like a list or a tree. When I read *build* I think of a process for compiling and linking software source code.

Answer (score 0):

I summarize the existing usage of `allocate`, `initialize`, `instantiate`, `make`, `build`, `create`, `add`, `insert`, and two more I needed in this comparison: `put` and `update`, below.

`allocate`; synonyms `alloc` (C); used for "allocating" or alloting space in **memory**

`initialize`; synonyms `init`, `__init__` (python)`; used for instantiating an object from a class or prototype

`instantiate`;; there's not a super strong case for this anywhere, but you're welcome to [look](https://github.com/search?p=1&q=instantiate&type=Code)

`make`;; in a shell scripting language (like `bash`), `make` is traditionally a command that manages compilation of different parts of a **C** or **C++** project. in **go**, `make` is a built-in function that offers functional syntax for instantiating an object of type slice, map, or chan.

`build`;; a lot of Makefiles will support this method because it falls in line with "building" or compiling a project.

`create`; synonyms `insert` and `POST` (REST); used for creating a new [web resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_resource) without an id. Errors if the web resource already exists.

`put`; synonyms `add`, `sadd` (redis), `zadd` (redis), `set` (redis), `PUT` (REST); creates a web resource by id. Updates the resource completely if it already exists.

`update`; synonyms `hset` (redis), `PATCH` (REST); updates a web resource by id. Some implementations throw, others create if resource does not exist.

I leave how you should be using these words to your discretion.